# doLayout() and ActionListener questions

Tags: java, swing, awt

I'm new to JSwing, so pardon me what might be some really beginners' questions.

After reading the tutorial on how to use top level containers, I tried the following code inside the actionPerformed event in a button:

```
private void colgarActionListener(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {

        auxButton = new JButton();
        auxButton.setSize(100,30);
        auxButton.setText("Me button");
        getContentPane().add(auxButton);
        getContentPane().doLayout();


}
```

As you expected, it occurs that it does not work. The button just does not appear. If I try a ridiculous thing such as:

```
getContentPane().setBackground(Color.red);
```

instead of

```
getContentPane().doLayout();
```

it works. What am I doing wrong?

And the last one: if I write a class which works as a custom ActionListener (with its constructor with parameters), where should I put it? As a private class inside the GUI code? It just feels so dirty... Or as a public class inside another package. maybe?

Thank you very much.

Regards.

Martín.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will want to read up on how the layout managers work and how to use them for that is one of the keys to using Swing (not JSwing by the way). The [Layout Manager Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html) is a great place to start.

For one, avoid using null layout and `setBounds(...)` For another, contentPane's usually use BorderLayout. Also, I've never seen `doLayout()` used before in this way. Instead I've usually seen `validate()` or `revalidate()` followed by `repaint()` called on the container after changing its components.

Comment: Thanks a million, Hovercraft Full Of Eels; that was immensely helpful. It worked and I'm reading that tutorial right now.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, an ActionListener is typically implemented as not only a private class, but an anonymous class, exactly at the use site. Anonymous class is when you write

```
x.addActionListener(new ActionListener() { public void actionPerformed(Event e) {
   ... stuff to do ...
}});
```

Comment: Thanks, Marko. I did not know about this. I'll rewrite my ActionListener as an anonymous class. It looks very elegant indeed.